# how to passing C# to javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi and Thanks in Advance,

I am populating asp:label in c# with displays some latitudes/longitude range boundaries and then validating.

asp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.bound = "<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.rangeLat_Bounds) %>";
//alert(bound);
</script>
.
.
.
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanelLatLongCoord" runat="server" HeaderText="Lat/Long" TabIndex="1">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="coord-btn btnLat_Long">
<asp:Button ID="btnDd" runat="server" Text="D.d" CssClass="coordinate-btn black" OnClick="Dd_Click" TabIndex="1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDMS" runat="server" Text="DMS" CssClass="coordinate-btn black" OnClick="DMS_Click" TabIndex="1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDMm" runat="server" Text="DM.m" CssClass="coordinate-btn black" OnClick="DMm_Click" TabIndex="1" />
</div>
<br />
<ul>
<li><span class="container-label">
<asp:Label ID="lblLat" runat="server" Text="Latitude" TabIndex="1"></asp:Label>
                            </span>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLat" runat="server" CssClass="container-input-field" SkinID="NumTextUpDown" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="rangeSetUp_Lat" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="Lat_Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLat"
                                    CssClass="errorMessage" ToolTip="Wrong Latitude Format" ClientValidationFunction="validate_Lat" TabIndex="1">
                                    <img alt="" src="images/no.png" />
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="RangeLat_CustomValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLat"
                                    CssClass="errorMessage" ToolTip="Latitude Out Of Range" ClientValidationFunction="rangeLat_validator" TabIndex="1">
<img alt="" src="images/no.png" />
</asp:CustomValidator>                      
</li>
<li><span class="container-label">
<asp:Label ID="lblLon" runat="server" Text="Longitude" TabIndex="1"></asp:Label>
</span>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLon" runat="server" CssClass="container-input-field" SkinID="NumTextUpDown"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="rangeSetUp_Lon" runat="server" Text="" TabIndex="1"></asp:Label>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="Lon_Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLon"
                                    CssClass="errorMessage" ToolTip="Wrong Longtitude Format" ClientValidationFunction="validate_Lon">
<img alt="" src="images/no.png" />
</asp:CustomValidator>

</li>
</ul>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
```

C#

```
protected void Dd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

.
.
.
Ranges range = new Ranges(rangeId);

String lowLat = parseOut(getCompassLat(range.LowLat));

String highLat = parseOut(getCompassLat(range.HighLat));

String rangeLat_Bounds = lowLat + " - " + highLat;

rangeSetUp_Lat.Text = rangeLat_Bounds;

JavaScriptSerializer js_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

.
.
.
}
```

external JS:

```
function rangeLat_validator(oSrc, args) {

//var bound = <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.rangeLat_Bounds) %>;  

var input = args.Value;

alert(window.bound);

}
```

When the user clicks the different buttons, it reformats asp:label as a different format for latitude and longitude. 
Problem is I can't get the rangeSetUp_Lat ID value in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the serialized value in quotes:

```
var bound = "<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.rangeLat_Bounds) %>";
```

If you still have problems after this, do you get any errors in the console?

EDIT:

It looks like the op was calling the serialization code from an external js file. 
Server side code only works in the main html file, so move the Serialize call in the main html, and bind it to a global variable (it would be better if you had a namespace for your vars, globals are bad in js):

```
window.bound = "<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.rangeLat_Bounds) %>";
```

And then access `bound` from the js function, simply by calling `window.bound`. Just make sure the js is called after the bound variable has been assigned in the html.

Comment: That just shows **<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.sJSON) %>**

Comment: Hm, I think this means that the serialization didn't work properly. is the js code located in the main page html, or in an external js file?

Comment: It is in an external js

Comment: Aha, then that is the answer. I think serialization only works for the main html file. create a variable in the html file, and use it in the js. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood, but I'm getting an error @ that window.bound part. **'ASP.mypage_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'javaSerial' and no extension method 'javaSerial' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.mypage_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** I update what I have for asp page.

Comment: This means you don't have a javaSerial property on you page, serverside, try creating a javaSerial property for your codebehind class.

Comment: something like this: **JavaScriptSerializer js_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        js_serializer.Serialize(rangeLat_Bounds);**

Comment: Yup, but you need to make it a property of the codebehind class, so that you can access it in the html page.

Comment: Does the class I populate the different latitudes/longitudes in need to be serialize?

Comment: No not the whole class, in the codebehind make a property that can be accessed from the aspx page, and in that property put the serialized value.

Comment: In my model class, I tried adding the property : JsonProperty but its giving me an error: **Error 15 The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** How can I add it?

Comment: Make the property of type String and write the serialized value into it.

Comment: something like this: **string bound = @"{""bound"":" + rangeLat_Bounds + "}";**

Comment: On my asp page, I am getting this error in vs: **'ASP.mypage' does not contain a definition for 'javaSerial' and no extension method 'javaSerial' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.mypage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** with the window.bound ... variable

Comment: So on the asp page I imported **<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>** and I'm still getting that error